# How to get the Wall of Flesh to face the right direction

Tags: terraria-console

On the PS Vita release of Terraria, I cannot fight the wall of flesh (fairly). I have built a long bridge across the underworld, but no matter where I drop the doll, the Wall of Flesh always spawns facing away from me and moving towards the closest border of the world (i.e. if I'm east of the spawn point, he will appear east of me, heading east). This makes for very quick, very messsy battles with him, which I inevitably lose.

I attempted to simply spawn him in the middle of the underworld and he simply did the same thing - he spawned to the side of me, moving away. Since I was behind him, he dragged me in front of him, which had the unfortunate effect of trapping me against an underworld skyscraper underneath my bridge, drowning in a pool of lava.

Comment: Have you experimented to see if the way your player is facing when you summon him affects the direction in which he arrives (it seems to make a difference on the PC)? Also, have you tried seeing if the same thing happens if you are west of the starting point (i.e. the WoF spawns west of you, heading west)? According to the wiki: "On Xbox, the Wall of Flesh will occasionally spawn backwards." Maybe this is a similar bug.

Comment: I've tried east and west, facing east/west for each. It doesn't seem to matter. I've also tried 6 times total. Each time the Wall spawned backwards. Although it's not solid evidence, it seems to tell me that it's not "occasional"

Comment: I've always noticed it spawns from the side I'm closest too. Which makes sense since that would give you the longest time to fight it. The behavior you describe makes no sense to me and seems like he is spawning either on the wrong side of you, or going the wrong direction.

Comment: @Katustrawfic: Based on the behavior I'm witnessing, he spawns on the correct side, but faces the wrong direction. On it's face, it's not that significant of a problem - since I'm well equipped to fight him. But because of that initial grab I end up getting sucked under my bridge. I might rebuild the bridge to be lower down and see if I can avoid that, but it involves significant movement of lava.

Comment: You could build the starting section of your bridge out of platforms. That way if you get sucked under it, you can more easily get above it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the left of the exact middle of the map, he will go the left toward you, and vise versa. Possibly try looking both ways when trying it.

Comment: I can confirm this is correct. Depending on your xpos it works out the difference from the left and right. If you are more to the right it will spawn the wall of flesh to your right side and move to the left, or if you are closer to the left it will spawn to the left and move right. It does this to provide you a fare chance of defeating it. Just think if you went all the way to the right spanwed it and it came from left to right, you got like 10 seconds to defeat it.

Answer (score -6):

Your answer lies [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh#Notes) my good friend.